# Differentiate between two graphs by image recognition

Tags: image-processing, graph, image-recognition

How can we compare images of two graphs and differentiate them based on their shape?
For ex, I have a collection of graphs with me which contain images of bar, pie and all other graphs. I will match it one image which i get from an another source.The source image will also be a graph. I need to find out what type of graph it is.
 

How do i match it with my collection set? 

 Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Not a simple task but computer vision sounds like the way to go. Something like openCV (cv2) can be used to detect shapes and colors in images

Comment: Can you show a sample graph images both source and target images